# If $A, B$ are self adjoint operators and $A \le B$, is $imA \subset imB$? is $ker(B) \subset ker(A)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

If $A, B$ be self adjoint operators and $A \le B$, is $imA \subset  imB$? is $ker(A) \subset ker(B)$?

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space is $A,B$ self adjoint operators on $H$, such that $A \le B$.

Is $ImA \subset ImB$ ?

from the definition of operator order I get that for every $x \in H$:
$$<Ax, x> \le <Bx,x>$$

but I don't see how that helps me to find the images of $A$ and $B$.

Help would be appreciated.

Now when also $A \ge 0$, is $Ker(B) \subset Ker(A)$ ?

I got to $<Ax,x> = 0$ for every $x \in Ker(B)$, since $<Ax,x> \ge 0$ and $<Ax,x> \le <Bx,x> = <0,x> = 0$

But I'm not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding ranges:

Simply assuming that $A\leq B$ does not imply that $\text{Ran}(A)\subseteq \text{Ran}(B)$, a counter-example being
$$-1\cdot I \leq 0\cdot I.$$

Perhaps assuming, in addition, that $A\geq 0$, might improve the chances of an affirmative answer.

---

Regarding kernels:

If $0\leq A\leq B$, and if $x\in\text{Ker}(B)$, then
$$
  \Vert A^{1/2}x\Vert^2 =
  \langle A^{1/2}x,A^{1/2}x \rangle =
  \langle Ax,x \rangle \leq 
  \langle Bx,x \rangle = 0,
  $$
so $A^{1/2}x=0$, and hence also
$$
  Ax = 
  A^{1/2}A^{1/2}x = 0,
  $$
so $x\in\text{Ker}(A)$.

Comment: Proving the inclusion of kernels is sufficient because ${\rm ran}(A^T)=(\ker A)^\perp$ and orthogonal complements are inclusion-reversing.

Comment: @runway, I guess your formula needs a closure on the LHS.